# How to fix InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application or request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, usersession

I am trying to store User Id in Session State like this.

```
var userInfo = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId");
```

I get an exception on the above line.  I have seen the fix for similar problem and most say that I need to call app.UseSession() before app.UseMvc() which I already am. I have no clue how to fix this. I have tried to rearrange the code in Startup.cs but was not able to fix this. Please assist.

> InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this
>   application or request

I am storing the user Id like this:

```
HttpContext.Session.Set("UserId", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user.UserId));
```

Also, the Current Property is always null so I am not sure if it is storing the UserID correctly. (See Snapshot attached)

[image]

I am using ASPNET Core 2.2.
Code in the Startup Configure method looks like this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseSession();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc();           

        }
```

In ConfigureServies method, I have added this

```
   services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

            });
```

Comment: Why are you setting the value with `bytes`, but trying to read it back as a `string`?

Comment: Are you calling `services.AddSession()` before `services.AddMvc()`?

Comment: Yes I am calling AddSession() befor AddMVC() and

Comment: @crgolden I have tried  HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserId", user.UserId);
but it doesnot work either.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add an implementation of `IDistributedCache` in `ConfigureServices?

See this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.0#configure-session-state) for a sample implementation:

> To enable the session middleware, Startup must contain:
>
> Any of the IDistributedCache memory caches. The IDistributedCache
>   implementation is used as a backing store for session. For more
>   information, see Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core. A call to
>   AddSession in ConfigureServices. A call to UseSession in Configure.

Note that they are using the memory based version of `IDistributedCache`, which is [not actually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.0#distributed-memory-cache) a distributed cache, but a local one.